# Error- "Failed to fetch the Solidity compiler from the following locations "

Tags: node.js, npm, solidity, truffle, ganache

MY truffle version
Truffle v5.7.1 (core: 5.7.1)
Ganache v7.6.0
Solidity - 0.8.17 (solc-js)
Node v19.3.0
Web3.js v1.8.1

****Failed to fetch the Solidity compiler from the following locations**:**

```
your text`https://relay.trufflesuite.com/solc/emscripten-wasm32/,https://binaries.soliditylang.org/emscripten-wasm32/,https://relay.trufflesuite.com/solc/emscripten-asmjs/,https://binaries.soliditylang.org/emscripten-asmjs/,https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/bin/,https://ethereum.github.io/solc-bin/bin/. Are you connected to the internet?
```

and nothing inside truffle files (Migrations , contracts , test and token_sell files).. All are empty
Thank You
#Truffle #Solidity #Nodejs #blockchain #Ganache

I am new to truffle , unable to run truffle compile , you can see my  error, I have already tried available solution on stakoverflow but I am unable to fix error.

Please Help
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Truffle in new versions doesn't create Migration.sol contract and its script inside the migrations folder. So when you run "truffle init" command, you see the empty contracts and migrations folders.

You can use "**truffle unbox**" instead of "truffle init". With this command, you'll have a sample project with many useful files and configurations. Although if you don't need each of them, simply delete that.

Source:
*https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/quickstart/*